# What happened to my Ni-MH battery?

Tags: batteries, damage, battery-chemistry

I made a little custom data logger.  It's powered by a rechargeable AA Ni-MH [battery](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1047689-REG/panasonic_bk_3mcca4ba_eneloop_aa_4_pack_2100.html?ap=y&c3api=1876%2C%7Bcreative%7D%2C%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=CjwKCAiA_ojVBRAlEiwAOLRxI4Z-hxgapMk6J7GXzf7lY59ttEWSw-u6IoeKfDkeiZvoT4AYiHMWlBoCp38QAvD_BwE).

Typically, it lasts about 2 weeks on one battery.  Then it uses a low voltage cutoff to sound a low battery alert, after which I swap in a new rechargeable battery and pop the old one back in the charger.

A few weeks ago, I had a little minor problem where the whole thing got wet.  The battery was found to be pretty hot.  The data logger was completely destroyed and has since been replaced.  After the battery had cooled down, I put it back in the charger (BQ-CC17).  It seemed to charge normally, but I can't say for sure since that charger doesn't calculate capacity or anything.

I used the (potentially damaged) battery in the (newly replaced) logger.  It worked fine for about a week, then abruptly died (no low battery alert).  My speculation is that the voltage dropped off so abruptly that the logger didn't have much or any time between the low voltage cutoff and the battery dying completely.  (The logger worked fine after putting in a new battery).

So, my question is this:
Is it possible for a battery to "fail" in such a way that it shows the following symptoms:

- Appears to work normally to roughly half its normal capacity
- Voltage drops off almost instantly

If the battery were totally destroyed (internal short circuit), I would not expect it to work at all, certainly not for half the time it normally does.  Is there an "intermittent short circuit" failure mode, where e.g. the short circuit occurred based on ambient temperature/humidity/phases of the moon, rather than being related to reduced capacity?

P.S. Please, no answers telling me that getting a new battery is cheap and easy.  I already have.  I just need to satisfy my academic curiosity.

Comment: "A few weeks ago, I had a little minor problem where the whole thing got wet. The battery was found to be pretty hot." What more do you need to know?

Comment: have you confirmed that the new logger raises a "low battery" alert?

Comment: @Trevor_G The answer to my question ("do Ni-MH batteries have a failure mode that matches these symptoms since the failure modes I know of would be expected to show different symptoms")

Comment: @jsotola Yes, it's been working totally normally ever since, so I don't think it was a problem with the logger, although I can't totally rule it out of course

Comment: @Selvek, a better question would be "how would I identify the failed battery in a group of "good" ones without waiting for it to discharge?"

Comment: @Selvek it got wet and it got hot... After that "normal" failure modes do not count. Short of doing a battery autopsy, you need to chalk it up to environmental failure.

Comment: My curiosity really stems from the fact that it seemed to be working totally normally at first.  You seem to be saying that there's no better answer to my question than "it's dead" but let's give the rest of the community a chance before we accept that.

Comment: I'm saying it's life-span was compromised. AFter that predicting it's failure is not possible.

Comment: BTW it's likely water got inside the battery structure. then dried out much later, leaving salts that shorted the thing out. But that's just a possible.

Comment: Dry Batteries are high pH dielectrics between highly conductive metal electrodes. Any foreign contamination of the electrolyte can affect its self-leakage.

Comment: In theory they should be water tight but perhaps slightly permeable to H2

Comment: "So, my question is this: Is it possible for a battery to "fail" in such a way that it shows the following symptoms:..." - yes, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360728/what-happened-to-my-ni-mh-battery